# Making ajax request from Chrome app with sandbox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I try to make an ajax call from my sandboxed page in my chrome app but i get this error :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://myserver.com/test. The
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
>   'https://myserver.com' that is not
>   equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

It seems that the cross domain is not allowed but in a sandboxed app it should be ..
Where is the mistake ?

Manifest.json :

```
{
    "name": "app",
    "description": "app",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "contextMenus",
        "cookies",
        "tabs",
        "notifications",
        "storage"
    ],
    "sandbox": {
        "pages": [
            "index.html"
        ]
    },
    "app": {
        "background": {
            "scripts": [
                "src/background.js"
            ]
        }
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "img/favicon.png",
        "128": "img/favicon.png"
    }
}
```

container.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>
    <iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-top-navigation" src="index.html" id="MdwSandBox1" width="800px" height="800px"></iframe>
 </body>
 </html>
```

background.js :

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('container.html', {
    'bounds': {
      'width': 800,
      'height': 800
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Sanboxed window can't have the same permissions like the app - that's whi it's sanboxed. Same Origin Policy will apply in the sanboxed page.

Comment: @PawełPsztyć So, I must remove allow-same-origin from <iframe> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/sandbox):

> A sandboxed page is not subject to the Content Security Policy (CSP)
>   used by the rest of the app or extension (it has its own separate CSP
>   value). This means that, for example, it can use inline script and
>   eval.

However:

> If not specified, the default *content_security_policy* value is sandbox
>   *allow-scripts allow-forms*. You can specify your CSP value to restrict
>   the sandbox even further, but it must have the sandbox directive **and
>   may not have the allow-same-origin token** (see the HTML5 specification
>   for possible sandbox tokens).

So you can't make this API call.

You can, however, make an API call from the app and pass the result to the iframe using [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage). 
The second way is to add [required headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#The_HTTP_response_headers) to your back-end - if you can control it.

Comment: The top of the docs you linked to now says:  "Warning: Starting in version 57, Chrome will no longer allow external web content (including embedded frames and scripts) inside sandboxed pages. Please use a webview instead."